# Get focus back when clicked outside the form

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a program to controle the audio volume by a remote control.
It needs to keep focused, otherwise it does not receive its commands anymore.
In order to get the focus back a used a timer, checking every second if the form still has the focus.
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Not Me.Focused Then
        Me.Activate()
    End If
End Sub
```

As long as I run it from within Visual Studio this works perfect.

When I close Visual Studio it does not take the focus back anymore.
I ran the program on another computer on which was no Visual Studio installed and it works!

What could be the problem?

Comment: just put it always on top: `Form.TopMost = True`

Comment: Topmost was set already.

Comment: whats the interval on your timer

Comment: Topmost was set already. Topmost makes it to stay on top but not to keep focused. The strange thing is i tried it on 3 computers with the same version of windows 10 home. On two of them is visual studio installed. On one of them it all works perfect als long as visual studio was not started. Closing visual studio does not help. On the other one it  does only work if use the start in visual studio. When visual studio is closed, the focus is lost if i click somewhere else. The interval is 1000, setting it to 5000 makes no difference.

Comment: well thats the thing no need to set it to 1000 or 5000 set it to 100

Comment: It might not make any difference, but the is the code you are running on the other computers compiled as a release or debug executable?

Comment: It is the debug executable. The executable works perfect and the timer does it's job but the me.activate does not work on all computers, even not on two computer with the same windows and framework versions installed. Why does it not work when visual basic is running, even when a run the executable from another location and why does it not work when visual basic is closed. Why does it work fine on another computer?

Comment: I tried the 100 interval also, it makes no difference at all. I have tried it on 500 and let the form background change color with in that timer too, so i saw the timer is working, it's only the me.activate command.

Comment: I did compile the code for .net 3, 4, 4.5 and 4.6, no difference